# Como retirar caractere ponto e vírgula com excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou tentando usar uma fórmula do excel para retirar o ponto e a vírgula, mas mesmo com a linha da fórmula correta não estou conseguindo resolver.
O que tenho agora é isso:

```
=SUBSTITUIR(SUBSTITUIR(K2;".";"");",00";"")
```

Estou tentando substituir os valores que estão assim: `2.000,00` para `2000` de forma que a coluna toda seja modificada, mas o valor fica `0,00`

Uma imagem da coluna.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse ponto que você esta vendo na coluna não existe. O excel mostra o conteúdo dessa maneira após a formatação, por isso que você não consegue substitui-lo.

Comment: Formate a coluna como GERAL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a fórmula `TEXTO` para reconfigurar a formatação dos números. Já que vc quer retirar os pontos (separadores de milhar) e as vírgulas (casas decimais), a sua fórmula vai ficar assim:

```
=TEXTO(K2;"0")
```

...ou, caso não queira ocultar os decimais diferentes de 0:

```
=TEXTO(K2;"Geral")
```

No seu caso, `SUBSTITUIR` só funciona quando vc está lidando com textos mesmo!

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda @Tash_Riser, facilitou muito.

Answer (score 1):

Altere a formatação de células para remover o **separador de milhar** e reduzir o número de **casas decimais** para zero.

[image: Formatação de células]